# How to boost certain documents if the search query contains a certain term/text in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, boost

**If the search query contains `fruits` I want to boost the products from a certain category?**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
          "constant_score": {
            "boost":   2,
            "filter": { 
              "term": { "categories": "3" }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have the above query, which gives a constant score to items with the category `3`, **I want to apply this constant score/boosting/increase relevancy only when a certain text (for example `fruits`) is present in the search term.**

Sample elasticsearch document

```
{
   "id" : 1231,
   "name" : {
       "ar" : "Arabic fruit name",
       "en" : "english fruit name"
   }
   "categories" : [3,1,3] // category ids because the same product is shown in multiple categories
}
```

How do I achieve this? I use elasticsearch 7.2

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "boost": 2,
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "categories": "3"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "name.ar": "fruit"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "name.en": "fruit"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If i understand correctly what you're looking for.
Btw, I suggest using "match_phrase" instead of "match" if you want to match "fruit name" exactly and not "fruit" or "name"

**Update:** (based on the comment)
In that case i'd suggest reorganizing your schema in the following manner:

```
"item": {
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": ["string"]
    },
    "language": {
      "type": ["string"]
    }
  }
}
```

So your sample would become:

```
{
   "id" : 1231,
   "item" : [
      {"name": "Arabic fruit name", "language": "ar"}
      {"name": "english fruit name", "language": "en"}
   ],
   "categories" : [3,1,3]
}
```

And then you can match against "item.name"

Why? Because the way ElasticSearch indexes (at least, by default) is to flatten your the array, so internally it looks like ["Arabic fruit name", "english fruit name"]

With your original sample, two different fields are created in the schema (name.ar and name.en), which is actually not a great design if you need to scale

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your input, But I was not looking for the matching with `name.*` fields rather the search query itself. For example, I want to promote fruits from a certain supplier when the search term contains `fruits`

Comment: Hi Shobi, just updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: Hi again, I greatly appreciate your help, But actually the answer you have posted wasn't quite I needed. Consider this, I have a category called fruits, and many companies sell apple(which is a fruit), But I strike a deal with one company that I will keep your brand at the top, So anyone search using the term `apple` or `fruit` I need to boost products or categories belong to that supplier at the top. So I don't want to match the term with the name of the document, rather I check if the query contains fruite then boost. I hope I am more clear,

Comment: Ultimately what I ended up doing is that I check from my code, if the search query contains fruit or apple then only I include the `constant_score` query in the elasticsearch call. At this point, this works fine. But I want more of an elasticsearch way because I need typo tolerance (fuzziness) and other elastic features. If you have any input on this matter, please let me know, I greatly appreciate your help. Gave a thumbs up already, If you have something more into this matter, I could also accept the answer. thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure that i understand correctly, but maybe you can look for each individual term in the query?
For example, if the user search input is "awesome apple", you try to match both "awesome" and "apple" against name.en and name.ar ? And you use a should query, with minimum_should_match = 1

Also, i don't know if you looked into this already? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html